# How to extract the return type of each value of an object without knowing the keys

Tags: typescript

EDIT: I edited the entire question to make it clearer, sorry for the misunderstandings

Given these 2 objects

```js
const check = {
  string: () => (str: any): string => "check stuff",
  number: () => (num: any): number => 123,
  email: () => (str: any): string => "email check"
}

const myobject =
{
  name: check.string(),
  age: check.number(),
  email: check.email(),
  test: check.number()
}
```

Ideally I would want to extract this type and it should be generalized in a way that I dont have to manually write the types every time I create a new check object

```js
type CustomType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  email: string;
  test: number;
}
```

Comment: Not quite clear what you're trying to do, but it looks like it might be something like [`io-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md) (a runtime type-checking system that can also be used to autogenerate corresponding TypeScript types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBTYBrGBeGBvAsAKBhmgCcBLMAcwC4YAKASgwD46SaBDMAT3ppPIrMYAIgTI00AK4AzacIA0+QmEkBbAEaJiNBkNorVHbrxgHNxIQEYATAGZFBGIlXtSAGx2N0LWmxicePigySiFhZ1c3OCRUYXwAX3x8UEhYVS4QdQArZFh0fFxHMHZVRBoxVAA6fkoGB0J2CjLo8UqzLTqlJxd3cpiUSoj3TscoRGg+1vbiBgSkvCguAAdEGABxRCgAFWXEAB4tlkxCwgBtAGkYchgURAzpGC2AXRoti6enAA8xsAATCDolSB7GIFAgRh4QgCMAA-DAAEqbSTEMA7FYHd4sV7vOZ4fCLFYwADC-UQvzRq0wG22uz2BMQIAe6UyOWAUCYAG4gA)

```
type GetType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> : T[K]
}

type CheckedType = GetType<typeof myobject>;
```

Comment: sorry, I edited the question because I made a mistake in the myobject definition, check.string() doesnt return a string but a function that returns a string (added code)

Comment: @MauroInsacco see `Playground` link, this works in your case if `check.string()` return string type

Comment: the string function should be () => () => "test" and not () => "test"